# Highcharts Column Chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highcharts to create a graph similar to what's shown below. As clear, the 1st column (100%) is a sum of all others. The approach I thought of was to have invisible series below each of the individual categories to give them their raised look. The only thing that's holding me back is the thought of the situation where I might have to deal with say 30+ categories (possible in our application). Is there any simpler way to achieve the same results?

I can't post the image directly as I'm a new user. Sorry.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBWIf.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the "low" property which is shown here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8JP8T/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{
            low: 1,
            y: 2
        }, {
            low: 2,
            y: 4  
        }, {
            low: 0,
            y: 4  
        }, {
            low: 4,
            y: 5  
        }]
    }]

});
```

You'll still have to preprocess your data to get the correct y value and low value, but it seems doable?

Comment: This seems to be a good idea. Will give it a shot and see if I can get the desired results. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

For column chart, for each point you can specify the `y` value and the corresponding `low` to create a **floating column**.

```
series: [{
    data: [
               {y: 29.9, low: 20}, 
               {y: 50, low: 20}, 
               {y: 100, low: 50}
    ]
}]
```

[See this example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/RZnUM/).